# Is there a way to cause git-reflog to show a date alongside each entry?

Tags: git, git-reflog, reflog

The git-reflog command doesn't by default show a date alongside each entry, which strikes me as a strange oversight; I think this would be very helpful.

Are there any command-line options, or other tweaks, which can be employed to cause it to show when each reflog entry was added? The [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) isn't forthcoming...

Answer (score 659, accepted):

Per the man page, you can use `git log` options, e.g.,

```
git reflog --pretty=short

git reflog --date=iso
```

Comment: This replaces the head number (or whatever the correct term is) with the date. Can you have both?

Comment: @Marco it seems you would have to use a custom format: `git reflog --format='%C(auto)%h %<|(17)%gd %C(blue)%ci%C(reset) %s'`.
I have added an alias for this: https://github.com/blueyed/dotfiles/commit/5c4e4be9fc6a56d1ccbc16398ac3fef007d5cc47

Comment: @blueyed Not quite the same - the `--date=iso` in the reflog command shows when that reflog entry was created, not the time of the commit. Still appreciate your alias, as I've used it to make a prettier reflog.

Comment: You can combine both: `git reflog --date=iso --pretty=short`

Comment: None of these comments attempting to answer "can you have both" actually give both.  @blueyed's comment gives the reflog selector in index format `HEAD@{2}` along with the /commit/ date. And @Herz3h's comment gives the reflog selector in timestamp format `HEAD@{2024-02-09 15:28:42 -0800}` but omits the index format. What I want is the reflog selector in both timestamp format and index format.

Answer (score 49):

You can use the `--walk-reflogs` variant of `git log`:

```
git log -g
```

This is rather verbose by default, and prints the date among other things. You can format it with the standard `--pretty=` flag.

You can also use the reflog command directly with the `--pretty=` flag to format the output.

```
git reflog --pretty='%cd %h %gd %gs'
```

In the format above, `%cd` shows the commit date to the left of the normal reflog output.

Comment: `%cd`, shows the date of the commit the reflog points to, unfortunately, which is not what I (or the OP) is after: we want the date of the reflog entry.

Comment: `git log --walk-reflogs --date=iso` just made my day

Comment: can `git reflog --pretty='%cd %h %gd %gs'` be colorful?

Comment: Perfection itself! thank you!

Answer (score 21):

You can use a custom format:

```
git reflog --format='%C(auto)%h %<|(20)%gd %C(blue)%cr%C(reset) %gs (%s)'
```

In the above format, `%h` is the commit hash, `%cr` is the relative committer date, `%gs` is the reflog subject, and, `%s` is the commit subject. Look at the [git-log docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for other possible placeholders. For instance, using `%ci` instead of `%cr` will show absolute commit dates.

You can save this in your ~/.gitconfig using a custom `pretty` format and refer to it via an alias:

```ini
[alias]
    rl = reflog --pretty=reflog
[pretty]
    reflog = %C(auto)%h %<|(20)%gd %C(blue)%cr%C(reset) %gs (%s)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `%gd` doesn't show the same date as `@{now}` does. When searching the reflog, knowing the exact time can be really important ("I know it was in the right state at 8:57" for example).

Comment: @ErikE - Just change the `cr` to `ci` to get the full timestamp of each action: `git reflog --format='%C(auto)%h %<|(20)%gd %C(blue)%ci%C(reset) %gs (%s)'`

Comment: instead of `(20)%gd` ; `(17)%gd` seems like better alignment

Answer (score 15):

[image]

If you just want to see the dates relative to the current time, you can use the following command:

```bash
git reflog --date=relative
```

To save some typing, you can create a git alias for it (`rl` - short for `reflog`):

```bash
git config --global alias.rl "reflog --date=relative"
```

And use the alias instead, like so (the `-10` at the end is to show the last 10 actions):

```bash
git rl -10
```

Comment: How can we show the head numbers like `HEAD@{16}` for all ?

Comment: @alper Just use `git reflog` for that format.

Comment: I want to have `git reflog` format while showing it as  sorted like with (`--date=relative`) flag

Comment: @alper I'd like to know too :).

Comment: I asked it as a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389262/how-can-i-use-git-reflog-format-while-showing-it-as-sorted-with-date-relati) , feel free to edit :-)

Answer (score 12):

Tell `git` in what format, either counted `reflog` entries or timed `reflog` entries, i.e.

```bash
git reflog @{now}    
git reflog @{0}
```

Comment: The programmer in me doesn't like the "natural language" dates inside the `{}`, but happily this technique also works with `--date=iso`.

Comment: Yes but I want to see BOTH formats in the same output. I'm trying to create a pretty format that gives BOTH the "index format" and the "timestamp format" of the reflog selector. Maybe that's not possible.

Answer (score 6):

Note git 2.10 (Q3 2016) improves the documentation about date with [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

See [commit 642833d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/642833db78aa5d7a72677aa9a9b013fb9a880f19), [commit 1a2a1e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a2a1e8eb93de2b89a32a52980ec7614fe9d154c) (27 Jul 2016), and [commit d38c7b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d38c7b2c2ce0116215eb05e11d442e9d03b887f4), [commit 522259d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/522259dc3adf49b59d76ee046a2d1361b171e32f), [commit 83c9f95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83c9f95cce99bcd383c78d614d614e72a4015e59), [commit 2b68222](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b68222d72fcb899ac87d8d48f066b49b5182f28) (22 Jul 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0d32799](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d3279962acab475a523cfde04a79761ff12f147), 08 Aug 2016)</sup>

The [`rev-list` options is updated](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0d3279962acab475a523cfde04a79761ff12f147/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L253-L270):

> The reflog designator in the output may be shown as `ref@{Nth}` (where `Nth` is the reverse-chronological index in the reflog) or as `ref@{timestamp}` (with the timestamp for that entry), depending on a few rules.

[It includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0d3279962acab475a523cfde04a79761ff12f147/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L753-L764):
- an update about `--date=raw`:

> shows the date as seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), followed by a space, and then the timezone as an offset from UTC (a `+` or `-` with four digits; the first two are hours, and the second two are minutes).
>   I.e., as if the timestamp were formatted with `strftime("%s %z")`).
>   Note that the `-local` option does not affect the `seconds-since-epoch`
>   value (which is always measured in UTC), but does switch the accompanying
>   timezone value.

And a new option: `--date=unix`

> shows the date as a Unix epoch timestamp (seconds since 1970).
>   As with `--raw`, this is always in UTC and therefore `-local` has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Format the `git reflog` output as the `glol` with ohmyzsh:

```
git reflog --pretty='%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %gs %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

Format the `git reflog` output as the `glod` with ohmyzsh:

```
git reflog --pretty='%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %gs %Cgreen(%ad) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

I made a custom plugin [git-mnz](https://github.com/manzapanza/git-mnz) for ohmyzsh with these two aliases `grlol`, `grlod` and some other aliases and functions.

** Sorry if didn't sent a PR to the git plugin, but there are [hundreds PR waiting to be merged](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pulls)..

Answer (score 2):

`git reflog --pretty=medium`

... but they make it really nasty to find out (there's no bash completion for git-log options, the `log` man page doesn't document the placeholder strings for various pretty built-in profiles, plus there are still some differences from the default `git-log` format, e.g. you'd have to pass `--abbrev`)