# exact timestamps git pull

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-pull, git-log

I'm trying to retrieve a list when a **git pull** was made on a Ubuntu server
eg.

- 2017-11-03 14:00:00 revision
- 2017-11-02 11:30:00 revision

Is this possible?

I tried **git log** but this shows me the commits and not the date when they were pulled.

Comment: Try `git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"`. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: Probably you need to see the reflog as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17369548/2303202)

Comment: This may help, https://askubuntu.com/questions/391082/how-to-see-time-stamps-in-bash-history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> git reflog --date=iso

It will give you information related to most of the logs. But sometimes if somebody has deleted ref logs then you will not have any information.