# Extract single commit from in between 2 rebases

Tags: git

I have a branch off of master, called A, that I wanted to create a new branch off of, B. Except I messed up and created B off of master.

Desired:

```
master
   \
    A
     \
      B
```

Actual:

```
master
 \  \
  A  B
```

B only has one commit that I need, but because it was based off of master and not A the diff is huge. To make things worse, I tried `git rebase -i A` and squashed everything except for the one commit I wanted seen, but this seemed to just rebase off of master again. So now I have a reflog that basically looks like this:

```
B@{0}: rebase: B onto master
B@{1}: commit
B@{2}: rebase: B onto master
B@{3}: branch B created
```

What I need to figure out is how to get just the one commit out and base it off of A so that I can make a pull request where the diff isn't huge.

Edit: might be good to note that A is not up-to-date with master, it is still many commits behind. So the erroneously rebased B is now "ahead" of A.

Comment: Does your `git reflog` still contain the unsquashed commits in B? If so, you might be able to use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_examples) to apply just those commits to A.

Comment: Note that B's reflog (`git reflog B`) will retain (for 30 days by default) all the original commits, pre-inappropriate-rebase, so that you can get them back. In this case I think `B@{3}` should be that one commit, or maybe it's `B@{1}`.

Comment: @OSH this worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem:

I created a new branch off of A, called C.

```
git checkout A
git checkout -b C
```

I then did `git cherry-pick SHA-B` where `SHA-B` is the SHA from the commit I wanted, which thankfully was saved in the reflog (`B@{1}` from the original post). Then all I had to do was resolve the conflicts and commit.

Answer (score 0):

> but because it was based off of master and not A the diff is huge

Still, you could try and [generate a patch, using the right base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37406982/6309)

```
git format-patch --base=$(git merge-base A master) -M -C B~..B
```

Then you can use [`git am` to apply it on top of `A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250170/6309)

If that `B` commit is the result of a rebase, you can indeed find it in [the reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) (90 days by default before being purged).
You can [use the date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089008/6309) as well to pinpoint the right old B:

```
 git reflog --format='%C(auto)%h %<|(20)%gd %C(blue)%cr%C(reset) %gs (%s)' B
```

Then you can use the `format-patch`, replacing `B~..B` by the old B commit reference found in the reflog.

Comment: When I do `git apply --stat patch_filename.patch`I still see a huge diff... is this expected, or should I only be seeing my intended commit here?