# restore git latest commit from local computer

Tags: git, git-commit

I created my code on local computer.

Once I pushed the code to git server.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "test"
git push -u ...
```

After that on the same branch I made lot of changes, and than did commit

```
git add -A
git commit -m "test"
```

The commit succeeded, but I instead of push I did

```
git checkout master
```

Then I realized I didn't push the code, so I did

```
git checkout mybranch
```

I realized again that the checkout I did was from the git server, and I didn't see code of mine, even I did commit.

I know that commit is kept on my local computer, but is my latest changes gone?

How can I restore the latest changes of mine?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Committing does not lose any changes.  If your working directory looks different after switching back to your feature branch, it might instead imply that you somehow didn't commit every file, and that those files got wiped out when switching branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) ([better than `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)) your branch and see your code.

But if not, check [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), and look for a recent commit SHA: try and `git switch --detach <SHA>` to inspect that commit, making sure your changes are there.

The [OP Eitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181056/eitan) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016485/restore-git-latest-commit-from-local-computer/67016539#comment118502527_67016539) having succeeded, using [`git log --pretty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65441929/6309):

> I found the date+time, and do checkout.
>
> ```
>  git reflog --pretty=format:"%H %an %ad"
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much . I did already checkout and not switch ... Hope it is not a dengarous thing to do. I don't want my code will gone. So after the commands you advised, I can do push, or should I run also other git commands before pushing?

Comment: @Eitan First, check if your code is there. If it is, reset your branch to it: `git switch -C yourBranch <SHA>`. Finally, git push.

Comment: The code isn't there. I will check out your advise after I backup all the folder of project

Comment: @Eitan If you have done a git commit, you should see that commit in `git reflog`

Comment: I am not at work right now. I will be on sunday. Than I figure out and let you know.

Comment: No I didn't, unfortunely. I ran also "git log" and the latest commit is more than a month.

Comment: I succeed. git reflog-pretty : I found the date+time, and do checkout.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441010/the-shortest-possible-output-from-git-log-containing-author-and-date

Comment: @Eitan Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The full command is git logref pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s". Should be logref. After that git checkout <yourbranch>. That will show the exact command on console how to checkout.

Comment: @Eitan Do you mean git reflog? (logref does not exist, unless is is an alias)

Comment: @Eitan OK but `git reflog pretty` is not an option I am familiar with (I don't see it in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

Comment: That's what I did. git reflog pretty. I can send the exact syntax on Sunday (sorry, again. In Israel there is holiday). There is a link. You may try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369254/is-there-a-way-to-cause-git-reflog-to-show-a-date-alongside-each-entry

Comment: Try git reflog --pretty=format:"%H %an %ad". That may work.